# Django : Long Object Attribute Error

Tags: python, django, django-views

This is my first introduction to 'Long' Objects, and I haven't found much in the Django docs on Querysets & long objects. I am trying to join two different queries into a list which I can email each user.

Two questions - is this the proper way to join these queries? If so, how do I access the `profile.user.email` attribute without hitting this long object error?

```
email_list = []
for user in request.user.get_profile().followers.all():
    email_list.append(user)


for profile in Profile.objects.filter(city=request.user.get_profile().city.id):    
    if not profile.user.id in email_list:
        print type(profile.user.id)
        email_list.append(profile.user.id)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'email'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding to the list 'long' objects (they are just numbers) instead of actual User instances:

```
email_list.append(profile.user.id)
```

it should be:

```
email_list.append(profile.user)
```

Comment: Thanks @Severio that was it. And thanks for explaining the Long objects. I saw long integers but didn't know they were the same. Much appreciated!